# Impossible to earn Hairboat hat on Expats.SE?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2014, secret-hats

I've successfully earned this on Travel, but it doesn't seem possible to earn it on Expats.  If certain powers could 'enable' this, it'd be appreciated ;)

Comment: I think Abby already has her hands full trying to clear her inbox. You can't expect her to post on every site just so she needs to clear her inbox even more.

Comment: @Mysticial I'm pretty sure she thought about it when agreeing to the hat. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Who says she _even knew about it_ beforehand?

Comment: @Jon now that would be a new kind of torture that even the CIA never dreamed of! :-D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Impossible!

You'd either have to:

- Write a good, on-topic question and send me the text, giving me permission to plagiarize your work with impunity, or
- Pick out one of your old questions for me to comment on (meaning *you* would get the inbox notification flood), or
- Let me disassociate one of your old posts and reassociate it with my account.

All of those options are *totally nuts* and I *do not condone them*.

Comment: You know... It's absolutely not fair that SE would create a hat that cannot be earned on a site!

Comment: You have a chameleon on your head, I'm wary of where you draw the line on "totally nuts".

Comment: @Gabe: They do not seem to have so much problems with generating badges that cannot be earned on most sites.

Comment: By "impossible", most people actually mean "improbable". Subtle, but there is a world of difference.

Comment: I thought you can only earn the hairboat hat if you comment on one of Abby's post? Not the other way around, or can you? @MarkMayo

Comment: @THelper I had to comment on her comment on my question. Hat achieved :)

Comment: So replying to one of abby's comments gets you the hat too? I thought it was only for posts.

Comment: And I can't seem to get this hat on [sf] either.

Comment: I imagine if you found a way to have a question Abby answers migrated to another site, you could earn the hat that way.

Answer (score 6):

Just ask abby to post something on the site you want to get the hat. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Hey, who's Abby? Can I ask her to give me a hat too?

Comment: @Amit well it's a secret hat... you're expected to put at least some effort researching it. (I have a policy of "no spoon feeding", sorry! :))

Comment: Oh! So you were being sarcastic about Abby then, I suppose :)

Comment: No sarcasm at all. She is a real user and in order to get the hat on specific site, she must have at least one question or answer on that site. :)

Comment: You'll find it if you seek, child @AmitJoki

Comment: @JashJacob seek child???

Comment: @Amit I think he meant it like "You will find it if you seek it, child" - in a parental tone. Being older than you, it makes some sense ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard ah! comma matters. Otherwise things could go *so* *so* wrong :)

Comment: lol, he just added a comma! /cc @Amit :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yup lol'ed. btw what's /cc?

Comment: @Amit "cc" is used in emails to send it to additional people. Here on SE, it's used to tell people "hey, see what I wrote, you might find it interesting" while not putting it in the beginning. (i.e. not a direct reply)

Comment: @ShadowWizard ah! Now I get it. I knew of carbon copy but not its different usage here on SE. Not able to earn hats, because my internet isn't giving a damn. Too slow :(